# How can I unblock someone?

Tags: geometry-dash

I accidentally blocked a friend of mine. How do I undo this?

Comment: on which platform?

Comment: @ardaozkal I'd assume PC, I don't think GEodash IOS even has a friend's system...

Comment: I'm on iOS. I rarely play PC.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to add an **illustrated solution:**

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Done!]

Comment: What a great answer for a not that great question! You could change the descriptions of the images to describe the steps, so if the pictures goes down, it will not ruin the quality of you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! When you go to your profile, click on the friends tab. In the top right corner there should be a button with a user icon on it. This will show a list of blocked users and allow you to unblock them.